# Can separate OSGi Deployment Packages use the same types of Resources?

Tags: java, osgi

The Deployment Admin Specification defines a way of creating Deployment Packages, which can contain Bundles and Resources.

I wanted to use the Deployment Admin to install two types of Deployment Packages. The first Deployment Package would contain the "framework" of the program; including all infrastructure level services and bundles, like the Configuration Admin, Declarative Services, etc. The second Deployment Package would contain the "data" of the program; almost exclusively Resources to be processed by the Resource Processors in the framework package.

In this situation, the Resource Processors would be in Customizer bundles in the framework package.

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  |
| Framework Deployment Package                     |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  |
| Declarative Services : Bundle                    |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  |
| Configuration Admin : Bundle                     |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  |
| Species Resource Processor : Bundle (Customizer) |
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------------+
|                         |
| Data Deployment Package |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
|                         |
| Configuration Resources |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
|                         |
| Species Resources       |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

When trying to do it this way, though, the second package is recognized as a foreign deployment package, and therefore can't be installed. The Specification, (114.5, Customizer) mentions

> As a Customizer bundle is started, it should register one or more Resource Processor services. These
> Resource Processor services must only be used by resources originating from the same Deployment
> Package. Customizer bundles must never process a resource from another Deployment Package,
> which must be ensured by the Deployment Admin service.

To check if this was true, I looked to the Auto Configuration Specification (115), which specifies an Autoconf Resource Processor, which is an extension of the Deployment Package Specification. It specifies a Resource Processor implementation, and processes Resources from the Deployment Package.

Based on this, if I wanted to use the Auto Configuration Specification, then I would seemingly need to include the Auto Configuration Bundle, and the Autoconf Resources within the same Deployment Package. This seems to result in another problem though. The Auto Configuration Bundle wouldn't be able to be used by another package, since a Resource Processor can only be used by Resources in the same package; additionally that Bundle couldn't be used by a separate, unrelated deployment package, because the Autoconf Bundle is already registered by the first package.

```
+---------------------------------+   +---------------------------------+
|                                 |   |                                 |
| First Deployment Package        |   | Second Deployment Package       |
|                                 |   |                                 |
+---------------------------------+   +---------------------------------+
|                                 |   |                                 |
| +-----------------------------+ |   | +-----------------------------+ |
| |                             | |   | |                             | |
| | Autoconf Bundle             | |   | | Autoconf Bundle             | |
| |                             | |   | |                             | |
| | SymbolicName: X             | |   | | SymbolicName: X             | |
| | Version 1.0                 | |   | | Version 1.0                 | |
| |                             | |   | |                             | |
| +-----------------------------+ |   | | Cannot be installed         | |
| |                             | |   | | because it's already        | |
| | Autoconf Resource Processor | |   | | installed by first          | |
| |                             | |   | |                             | |
| | Can only be used by         | |   | +-----------------------------+ |
| | this Deployment Package     | |   | |                             | |
| |                             | |   | | Autoconf Resource Processor | |
| +-----------------------------+ |   | |                             | |
|                                 |   | | Can only be used by         | |
| Autoconf Resource               |   | | this Deployment Package     | |
|                                 |   | |                             | |
+---------------------------------+   | +-----------------------------+ |
                                      |                                 |
                                      | Autoconf Resource               |
                                      |                                 |
                                      | Cannot be used because Bundle   |
                                      | containing Resource Processor   |
                                      | isn't installed, and therefore  |
                                      | can't be used by only this      |
                                      | Deployment Package              |
                                      |                                 |
                                      +---------------------------------+
```

It seems like if two Deployment Packages wanted to use Autoconf Resources, we would be blocked because the Resource Processor is either installed as a Bundle, and therefore unusable by the Deployment Admin because it is not in a Deployment Package, or as part of a single Deployment Package, and no other Deployment Package can ever use that version of that Bundle.

Is my understanding correct then, that two Deployment Packages not only have to be separate, but also completely unrelated, to the point of not reusing even a single Bundle? If this is the case, then does that mean that it is impossible to have two Deployment Packages with Autoconf Resources; or at least, two packages with the same type of Resource?